# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: errors, parse

I am trying to use following codes to have an email share button in a WordPress website. But adding this codes in single.php shows "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in .......... in line 72". 
Please help me someone to fix this issue.

```
<?php echo "<a href="mailto:type%20email%20address%20here?subject=I%20wanted%20to%20share%20this%20post%20with%20you%20from%20<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&body=<?php the_title('','',true); ?>%20%20%3A%20%20<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>%20%20%2D%20%20%28%20<?php the_permalink(); ?>%20%29" title="Email to a friend/colleague" target="_blank">Share via Email</a>"; ?>
```

Comment: Enclose the string in single quotes and you'll be fine. That having been said, this question is purely PHP related and in no way specific to WordPress. And hence, [*off-topic*](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Hi Johannes, thank you very much for responding. I know its PHP related problem but in a WordPress site. I guessed WordPress experts would be able to help. I have little knowledge in PHP. Could you tell me exactly where I should edit to fix the issue? Again thanks.

Comment: @JohannesPille: It won't work - he has nested <?php ?> tags in there too...

Comment: Did not scroll that far, I suppose.

Comment: :) I know. I've done the same mistake :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a very good practice to echo html code. Also you have errors with quotes.

Correct way to do this would be:

```
<a href="mailto:type%20email%20address%20here?subject=I%20wanted%20to%20share%20this%20post%20with%20you%20from%20<?php echo rawurlencode(get_bloginfo('name')); ?>&body=<?php echo rawurlencode(get_the_title()); ?>%20%20%3A%20%20<?php echo rawurlencode(get_the_excerpt()); ?>%20%20%2D%20%20%28%20<?php echo rawurlencode(get_permalink()); ?>%20%29" title="Email to a friend/colleague" target="_blank">Share via Email</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Krzysiek. The codes not working. Would you please check the codes again?

Comment: It should be OK. How are you pasting it?

Comment: When email client opens on clicking "Share via Email", title and excerpt have + after every words. Like this This+is+the+Title+of+the+Post : Welcome+to+WordPress.+This+is+your+first+post. () (here should be post link. but its blank)

Comment: Updated answer. It should be OK now.

Comment: You are awesome, Krzysiek!!!! Several persons tried to help me on this but didn't succeed except you! Indeed you are a superstar :) Thanks a billion...

Comment: Hi Krzysiek, sorry for disturbing you again. Another problem now I'm facing. Please reply on this post if you know how to fix that http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107101/getting-8217-instead-of-apostrophe-and-instead-of-space